# React hook customized for fetch api login

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi everyone I'm trying to create my own custom hook to login into my app, so I created the following hook which I called `useApiRequestLogin`

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export const useApiRequestLogin = () =>{
  const [dataToSend,setDataToSend] = useState({ hits: [] })
  const [dataRc, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [dataToSend]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    let isMounted = true;
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios.post('/api/auth/login',dataToSend, {timeout: 10000},{
    }).then((res) => {
      if(isMounted){
        setData(res.data);
        setIsError(null);
      }
      }).catch((error) => {
        if(isMounted){
          setIsError(error);
          setData(null);
        }
      }).finally(()=> isMounted && setIsLoading(false));
      return ()=> (isMounted = false);
  };
return [{ dataRc, isLoading, isError }, setDataToSend];
}
```

And this is my login component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import {useApiRequestLogin} from '../adapters/ApiRequest';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Login(){
    const history = useHistory();
    const {register, handleSubmit,reset, errors} = useForm();
    const [{ dataRc, isLoading, isError,urlS }, doFetch] = useApiRequestLogin();
    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        doFetch(data);
        if(dataRc){
            localStorage.setItem('token',dataRc.token);
            history.push('/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
          //foo
        }
    }
    return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
      {errors.firstName?.type === 'required' && "First name is required"}

      <input {...register("password", { required: true })} />
      {errors.password&& "password is required"}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

My problems are two, how do I make `useApiRequestLogin` be called only when I submit and not when the page is loaded?

And then the biggest problem is that the variables `dataRc`, `isLoading`, `isError`, are not updated instantly, that is, if I insert the correct data and then the wrong ones, the login will be performed because it refers to a previous state, so it is as if were desynchronized, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: For the hook being called on the top level shouldn't be any issue. As per the react documentation the react hooks are to be called on the top level. Also you can consider this as a good practise. 
https://blog.bitsrc.io/best-practices-with-react-hooks-69d7e4af69a7. check this out for best practise of making a custom hook.

Comment: I have read your link but it does not claim to have violated any logic, I would like to understand how I can make my hook useApiRequestLogin, return the data to me correctly not that it is always in a state prior to what it really should be, for example, if I log in by entering the correct user and password, I will have to enter them twice because the previous states are always returned and I don't know how to fix this problem.